# Find Maximum Index in Google Datastore (Pagination in Blog System)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I have a series of blog posts as entities. I will receive a URL that looks like this: `/blog/page/1`. I would like to access the most recent 5 posts in this case. In the case of `/blog/page/2`, I want the 6-10th most recent.

So allow me to do an [X-Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because I think this is the only way:

How do I find the maximum of a value in numerous entities with Google Cloud Platform Datastore? (I'm using `ndb`)

I can give each entity an ID value, and then fetch 5 from a query where `ID < maxIndex - page * 5` sorted by `ID`.

But, how do I find `maxIndex`? Do I fetch 1 from a query ordered by `ID`, find it's `ID`, and then run the previous operation? That seems somewhat slow for *every pageview*.

How can I either A) Find the max index quickly or B) Implement pagination otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: have you seen cursors? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors

Comment: Thanks very much. I did look at cursors. Perhaps you could help me with this X-Y I ran into using that problem. I want the url `/page/2` to be able to work: Wouldn't I have to pass that ugly cursor data in the URL?

Comment: I guess you could store the cursor in the users session perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cursors you can use a Datastore entry to store the cursor then send the Datastore key back and forth. Obscuring it by sending data via post requests is another option.

To answer your original question: To get the the top entry do a query with a [sort](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Sort_orders) with a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Retrieving_results) of 1. This will actually read all the Datastore entries so you should do a [keys only](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Keys_only_queries) search to get the ID (keys only is free) then get the actual posts. So something like this:

```
class IndexPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    maxIndex = Posts.query().order(-Posts.PostIndex).fetch(limit=1, keys_only=True)[0].get().PostIndex        
    page_number = 0
    post_lists = getPageResults(maxIndex, page_number)
    while len(post_lists) > 1:
        self.response.write("====================PAGE NUMBER %i===================</br>" % page_number)
        for post in post_lists:
            self.response.write(str(post.get().PostIndex) + "</br>")
        page_number += 1
        post_lists = getPageResults(maxIndex, page_number)


def getPageResults(maxIndex, page):
    index_range = (maxIndex - (page*5))
    post_index_list = range(index_range, index_range-5, -1)
    return Posts.query(Posts.PostIndex.IN(post_index_list)).order(-Posts.PostIndex).fetch(limit=5, keys_only=True)
```

Keep in mind I threw this together in a few minutes to illustrate using keys_only and the other points I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I had implemented at the time of asking the question. I realized that I was being stupid when considering the speed (I wasn't even thinking about how databases are indexed). Thank you very much for the tip on `keys_only`, as well!

Comment: Sorry, I was just getting to adding `keys_only`. I'm actually not sure that `keys_only` is going to help me, since my `PostIndex` is not actually an ndb key. When you call `.get()` in line 3, you're still retrieving the whole entity. So I think you must just use `Posts.query().order(-Posts.PostIndex).get().PostIndex`. Additionally, I believe properties are retrieved lazily, so it doesn't matter anyway. I don't think `keys_only` is useful in my case.

Comment: The reason for the keys_only is the limit doesn't stop reading. It will read all million entities even if you only want the first. As a keys_only is free it will save you money in the long run.  So it gets the whole list of indexes via keys only. I then run the get on the first entity in the list to get the actual values to get the post index. If I broke it down into the 2 original steps it would be clearer

Comment: @Cosine I can confirm that Ryan is right in his comment. If you do a get on a million entity, even with a limit of 2, the datastore will count it as a million read, so you have to be careful using limits. Ryan's method of doing it with a Keys_only means your "million" read will not cost you anything, you'll only pay when you retrieve the entity by using its key. An added benefit is that a "get by key" forces strong consistency (always fun)